# Spring Boot 3.0.4 webflux having 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

After upgrading to Spring Boot 3.0.4 webflux from 2.7.5, I am getting "415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE". Service was accepting and returning the xml content. It was working fine before.

```
    @PostMapping(
      value = "/sides/Request",
      consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
      produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
  public Mono<ResponseModel> getSsi(@RequestBody Mono<RequestModel> requestModelMono) {...
}
```

POM:

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
 
        </dependency>

    

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
          
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: I am getting a 415 on spring-boot 2.7.5. The problem is resolved if I take out the Mono<> from (@RequestBody Mono<RequestModel>.I would like to try to simulate. Could you possibly include the complete pom and any other specifics to help be get this running?

Comment: @John Williams not working even after removing mono. It's part of big project. So, could you please try in any project generated from https://start.spring.io/  with the above mentioned jaxb dependecy and webflux and spring boot 3.0.5

Comment: Just did same and am also getting the 415 error. I am 90% sure its connected to the move of javax.xml.bind to jakarta.xml.bind from Java 11 -> Java 17. I will take a look at the fix.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is that **javax.xml.bind** in Java 11 has been replaced with **jakarta.xml.bind** in Java 17.

Fix this by updating the dependencies by removing `javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1` and replacing with `jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api` (version managed from spring-boot-starter-parent).

All the `import javax.xml.bind` must be changed to `import jakarta.xml.bind` in your POJOs if they are handcoded.

Alternatively, if the XML backing classes are generated the jaxb refs in the XSDSchema must changed as follows:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jxb:version="1.0"
```

must be changed to

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jxb:version="3.0"
```

Here is source from a small project that works correctly:

pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version> <!--or 2.7.10 -->
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>monostuff</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>monostuff</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version><!--or 11 -->
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
<!-- Java 11 <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>2.3.0</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <!-- or Java 11 <version>2.3.0</version> -->
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <!-- or Java 11 <version>2.3.0</version> -->
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
        <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Controller

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@RestController
public class MyController {
   @PostMapping(
              value = "/sides/Request",
              consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE,
              produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
          public Mono<ResponseModel> getSsi(@RequestBody Mono<RequestModel> requestModelMono) { 
   
       
         ResponseModel responseModel = new ResponseModel();
        return Mono.just(responseModel);
        }
}
```

RequestModel

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Date;

// were javax.xml.bind in java 11 / string boot 2
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType()
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class RequestModel {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String author;
private Date date;

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name = "title")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlTransient
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

}
```

ResponseModel

```
package com.example.demo;

import java.util.Date;

// were javax.xml.bind in java 11 / string boot 2 
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;
import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

import lombok.Data;

@XmlRootElement(name = "book")
@XmlType()
@Data
public class ResponseModel {

private Long id;
private String name;
private String author;
private Date date;

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement(name = "title")
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@XmlTransient
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}

}
```

Sample CURL:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/sides/Request --header "Content-Type: application/xml" --data "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><book id=\"1\"><title>Book1</title><date>2016-11-12T11:25:12.227+07:00</date></book>"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for provinding the working solution !! It worked. :)