# jaxb2 Maven Plugin Fails to generate Java Packages with correct Imports or throws errors

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm currently using the Maven jaxb2 plugin to generate POJOs from my XSDs. I have a *few* issues so far.

I have 1 parent XSD that imports another XSD that in turn imports 2 other XSDs.
`a.xsd -> b.xsd -> (c.xsd & d.xsd)`
In my POM file configuration for the plugin, I'm only including the top-most parent XSD (a.xsd).

##### Issue

Two of the imported XSDs have elements with the same name so initially, when I ran the plugin I received the error:

> A class/interface with the same name {class/interface} is already in use. Use a class customization to resolve this conflict.

After a lot of googling and pouring over StackOverflow I came across the solution to use a custom binding file to handle renaming the offending classes/elements.

###### bindings.xjb

```xml
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" version="2.0">

    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="./sets.xsd">
        <jaxb:schemaBindings>
            <jaxb:package name="foo.set"/>
        </jaxb:schemaBindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='SomeType']">
            <jaxb:class name="SetsSomeType"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='InfoType']">
            <jaxb:class name="SetsInfoType"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
        <jaxb:bindings node="//xsd:complexType[@name='OpsType']">
            <jaxb:class name="SetsOpsType"/>
        </jaxb:bindings>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

###### jaxb2 plugin configuration

```xml
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xsd-to-java</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <packageName>some.package.name.bindings</packageName>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/xsd/package/messages.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>src/main/xsd/package/bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                    <xjbExcludeFilters>
                        <filter implementation="org.codehaus.mojo.jaxb2.shared.filters.pattern.PatternFileFilter">
                            <patterns>
                                <pattern>\.xsd</pattern>
                            </patterns>
                        </filter>
                    </xjbExcludeFilters>
                    <!--<arguments>
                        <argument>-XautoNameResolution</argument>
                    </arguments>-->

                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

This resulted in the following error:

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: not an external binding file. The root element must be {https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb}bindings but it is {http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb}bindings

I cannot for the life of me understand why it's insisting on 'https://jakarta/ee/xml/ns/jaxb`!

Additionally, I also tried adding the `-XautoNameResolution` as an argument to my plugin configuration and got the same error.

I'm running the build from the Maven panel in IntelliJ too.

Any idea what I could be missing or have misconfigured?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The https://jakarta/ee/xml/ns/jaxb issue is that jaxb has moved from `javax.xml.bind` to `jakarta.xml.bind` in Java 17 (also SpringBoot 3 and Spring 6), breaking all sorts sorts of stuff. Same with javax.validation -> jakarta.validation.

Anyway, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75825235/spring-boot-3-0-4-webflux-having-415-unsupported-media-type/75827535#75827535) for how to fix

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! That fixed my issue (after refactoring a bunch of imports throughout the project ;-) )